# finding number of submatrices of a matrix of given order?

Tags: matrices

How do we calculate the number of possible submatrices of a matrix of order $5\times 6$?

options for the answer are:

1. $465$
2. $1953$
3. $2048$
4. $30$

Comment: What data characterise a submatrix?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: select a subset of rows and then a subset of columns.  Empty sets are not allowed.

Comment: it is given 31*63=1953 in the book in which i read.but i dint understand this? can anyone explain me this?

Comment: There are $2^5 = 32$ subsets of the $5$ rows, but the empty set is not allowed, so that leaves $31$.  Similarly for the columns.

Comment: yeah i got it..thanks